# Adding Vendor library to Symfony 2 to be accessed via the container

Tags: php, symfony, service

I'm still very new to symfony and trying to include the following libary into my project so i can access it as using `$myThing = $container->get('myThing');`
The library in question is: https://github.com/gridiron-guru/FantasyDataAPI

I have the library downloaded and put into my vendors directory via composers require:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.4.*",
        ...
        "gridiron-guru/fantasy-data-api" : "1.*"
    },
```

I've added to my app\config.yml:

```
parameters:
    fantasyapi.key:  **********************c5o67

services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        FantasyDataAPI
        arguments:    ["%fantasyapi.key%"]
```

When i run container:debug i see:

```
fantasy_api                   container FantasyDataAPI
```

I have created a file called play.php in the project root:

```
    <?php

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;


    $loader = require_once __DIR__.'/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
    Debug::enable();

    require_once __DIR__.'/app/AppKernel.php';

    $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    $kernel->boot();

    $container = $kernel->getContainer();
    $container->enterScope('request');
    $container->set('request', $request);

    /** all the setup is complete!! */

    $client = new FantasyDataAPI\Client( "**********************c5o67" );
$result = $client->FantasyPlayers([]);

var_dump($result)
```

;

This produces the desired result but its not using my service.

If i change it to us my service:

```
$client = $container->get('fantasy_api');
$result = $client->FantasyPlayers([]);

var_dump($result);
```

i get an error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FantasyDataAPI' not found in D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 729
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\play.php:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\play.php:24
PHP   3. appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFantasyApiService() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2059

Fatal error: Class 'FantasyDataAPI' not found in D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 729

Call Stack:
    0.0010     128760   1. {main}() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\play.php:0
    0.2940    4392496   2. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\play.php:24
    0.2940    4392704   3. appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFantasyApiService() D:\Ampps\www\NFLtest\app\bootstrap.php.cache:2059
```

I'm sure its to do with namespaces, does something in the library need to be change?

How can i add this library as a service?

****Solved**** 
was indeed a problem with namespaces thanks David

adding FantasyDataAPI/Client fixed the issue.

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified name: ie you need to use the namespace.

Comment: the fully qualified name is FantasyDataAPI the class is client so FantasyDataAPI/Client is the FQN

Comment: Use \FantasyDataAPI.  The leading backslash is how php access non-namespaced classes from within a namespace.  Your new works without a back slash because your app.php file is not in a namespace.  But the container is.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give the full namespace to a class you want to instantiate.

Use `FantasyDataAPI\Client` instead of `FantasyDataAPI`:

```
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        FantasyDataAPI\Client
        arguments:    ["%fantasyapi.key%"]
```